# converting an array to doubles

Tags: java, double

Sorry I am new to coding, I am trying to convert an array to doubles but I want to skip over the first line of the array.

I have the following code

```
    public void organisedata()
{


    try (BufferedReader readbuffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filepath))) {
        String strRead;
        int count=0;

        //strRead = readbuffer.readLine() != null;

        while ((strRead = readbuffer.readLine()) != null) {
            count++;

            String splitarray[] = strRead.split("\t");
            String firstentry = splitarray[0];
            String secondentry = splitarray[1];
            String thirdentry = splitarray[2];
            String fourthentry = splitarray[3];
            String fifthentry = splitarray[4];
            String sixthentry = splitarray[5];
            String seventhentry = splitarray[6];
            String eighthentry = splitarray[7];
            String ninthentry = splitarray[8];
            String tenthentry = splitarray[9];
            String eleventhentry = splitarray[10];
            String twelvethentry = splitarray[11];
            String thirteenthentry = splitarray[12];
            String fourteenthentry = splitarray[13];
            String fifthteebthentry = splitarray[14];
            String sixteenthentry = splitarray[15];
            String seventeenthentry = splitarray[16];
            String eightteenhentry = splitarray[17];

            System.out.println(firstentry + " " + secondentry + " " +thirdentry + " " + fourthentry+ " " + fifthentry + " " + sixthentry + " " +seventhentry + " " + eighthentry+ " " +ninthentry+ " " +tenthentry+ " " +eleventhentry+ " " +twelvethentry+ " " +thirteenthentry+ " " +fourteenthentry+ " " +sixteenthentry+ " " +seventeenthentry+ " " +eightteenhentry);


            int length =splitarray.length;
            double[] Exprs_Val=new double[length] ;
            for (int i = 1; i< length+1; i++)
            { System.out.println (splitarray[i]);
                Exprs_Val[i-1]=Double.parseDouble(splitarray[i]);

            }
            System.out.println( "Double Array is" +Exprs_Val+"");

        }

    }   catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.format("IOException: %s%n", e);
    }
}
```

this code compiles, the first part is spilting my array and them I want to covert to doubles,  however when I run it i get the following error in the terminal.

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "GSM119944"
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
at serialanova.organisedata(serialanova.java:142)
at serialanova.<init>(serialanova.java:41)
```

input file

ProbeSetID  GSM119944   GSM119945   GSM119946   GSM119947   GSM119948   GSM119949   GSM119950   GSM119951   GSM119952   GSM119953   GSM119954   GSM119955   GSM119956   GSM119957   GSM119958   GSM119959   GSM119960
1007_s_at   11.37651913 11.82674322 11.12302175 11.7434386  12.17296072 11.52200918 11.28840678 11.36454405 11.783231   12.10269679 12.14193446 12.14167191 11.54116091 12.06920648 11.52945627 9.692066334 11.24298832
1053_at 7.270398138 7.534450178 7.169297224 7.730833029 6.728913697 7.033900213 8.152550207 7.357942158 7.811468938 6.704366054 7.723678376 7.607720233 6.90457947  6.837490079 7.437898775 7.608959838 6.704647979
117_at  8.172823015 8.350567625 8.216072585 8.052177294 7.940714093 8.122496258 8.246269493 7.597745286 8.809971026 7.299070143 7.808596965 8.390707085 7.653513989 8.680944931 8.050872759 9.242005826 8.253535243
121_at  10.06419511 11.19368787 9.846188898 10.54999199 10.17272162 10.35728397 11.36108085 10.44613907 11.16554125 10.28543507 10.12355559 10.53273535 10.37933453 10.48754106 10.54241919 10.24804257 10.20725888
1255_g_at   6.256425264 6.830607291 5.825010391 6.098156783 6.104971084 5.818458175 6.355994791 6.31131152  7.366573808 5.577411502 4.570793941 5.046955968 6.561945382 5.897955196 5.40272477  5.957542041 6.201036979
1294_at 9.34788666  9.540260108 9.229501062 9.4643475   9.764903421 9.962180073 9.30045006  9.230649257 9.783263485 8.749284991 9.466964913 9.653450466 9.076623297 9.827835105 9.096732184 9.441370378 9.102000375
1316_at 7.444821595 8.381578766 7.438297503 7.262875144 7.231406742 7.732812769 7.752616718 7.766491871 8.276988479 7.533668585 6.982003095 7.828565136 7.119046748 7.649261001 7.651054255 7.510538903 7.366082474
1320_at 4.645388076 4.776598113 6.887012613 7.275902937 6.087877539 6.841132977 5.35934964  4.514507696 7.731723615 7.531067564 3.93247219  6.254824208 7.125020518 4.264763543 6.58014897  6.747268108 4.255204695
1405_i_at   10.45746907 8.927090755 9.917244096 8.238428875 8.957485742 8.461268645 9.401926859 9.717728257 7.906093812 5.908940792 10.97142109 8.168480828 8.337354139 6.86662155  9.56724363  9.489516637 10.39147919
1431_at 6.095264756 6.96721331  6.271370399 7.683606278 5.608434719 7.288548664 6.613085022 6.386992852 7.172060044 6.283570929 6.027862996 5.749611048 6.410620957 6.074076381 6.454061235 6.894934672 5.412199729
1438_at 8.165022563 8.601696109 8.127203872 8.330128005 7.194363227 7.447903155 7.979068416 7.625896467 8.669911995 8.894808527 6.943193024 8.47454858  10.16632365 7.728061128 7.388841509 7.525051872 7.655379957
1487_at 8.717167566 8.948921171 8.482996756 9.224306979 9.006381141 9.004412187 8.89076478  8.95289573  9.135284813 8.730470712 8.910346798 8.815229729 8.880683672 8.460717188 8.636235029 8.979530875 8.45864663
1494_f_at   8.569307104 9.272563796 8.099782465 8.482816224 8.728872241 8.893912706 9.24799404  8.36195164  9.190847721 8.682856425 7.89146507  12.02424423 8.988280669 8.810714569 8.354246959 8.549493485 8.240601365
1598_g_at   11.55719086 11.63133551 11.46310591 11.22502937 11.16871228 11.6159067  11.18760975 10.91536891 12.13072975 11.3505339  11.15684203 11.29458341 11.46845278 10.94348537 11.48669348 12.11094884 11.55747693
160020_at   9.985305832 10.3690069  10.55363004 9.652222774 9.014218196 9.88234234  10.49070862 9.871292777 10.01205992 9.537328536 8.667695292 9.547152914 9.949466166 10.10975472 10.12075296 10.41474576 9.828687732
1729_at 10.36136675 9.817158399 9.832590412 9.028762922 8.621520517 8.93287561  8.083130024 8.679599605 9.290645997 8.960094561 9.127580834 9.846010315 8.903352147 9.109550293 8.828138425 8.705080643 8.263143078
177_at  6.692846164 7.789500294 7.379171629 6.805409654 6.915594737 7.092665506 7.144847932 5.378081482 7.822745778 7.184686193 6.954013623 6.72866045  7.372252198 6.647955518 7.887163057 7.844297173 6.518292095
1773_at 7.427238548 7.202968595 7.614420308 8.008938758 7.290033624 7.542243543 6.537122301 6.967084261 6.776254109 8.008170278 6.877636117 7.119945885 8.024472104 7.716287778 7.16699594  7.433050044 7.651089965
179_at  9.267843565 9.852632546 9.480728984 10.11332621 9.281188401 9.522899304 9.763622175 9.384980124 10.41921144 9.687657195 9.227467149 9.72530832  9.839523301 9.714825974 9.873303264 9.488571197 9.638988643

if you need anymore of my code let me know. 
Thanks

Comment: GSM119944 isn't in the format of a double, you should find the array index which has that value and either remove it or manipulate the string so that it will be accepted by the parseDouble() method

Comment: You seem to be doing absolutely correct operation except that file has multiple types of data and not only double. If you're sure and know that nth column is not double or a number, you can skip that column in for loop.

Comment: @RaviKumarGupta  
it is the row of the array that isnt values.. how do i skip this?

Comment: Can you please attach the file?

Comment: @RaviKumarGupta sorry new to this how do i do that?

Comment: Upload it anywhere and share the link. :)

Comment: Or add the file content in your question..

Comment: @RaviKumarGuptam thats it there,

Comment: If you see in your file, the first line is not a series of doubles.. they are alphanumeric texts.. you need to skip that line. To do that.. either update your input file to remove that line. Or use strRead = readbuffer.readLine(); just before your while loop. Just once. That will read a line and do nothing. When your while loop starts it will actually be reading second line. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is with your input file.

Your error is telling you that `"GSM119944"` is not the format of a double, because it has alphabetic characters.

The error is thrown on this line when you try to turn this string into a double.

```
Exprs_Val[i-1] = Double.parseDouble(splitarray[i]);
```

If you cannot fix your input, then you can use a `try-catch` block to handle this invalid input.  That might look something like this, but what you want to do in an error scenario is up to you.

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    System.out.println (splitarray[i]);
    try {
        Exprs_Val[i] = Double.parseDouble(splitarray[i]);
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        // This entry cannot be parsed into a double, insert a value to indicate an error
        Exprs_Val[i] = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code:

1:

You are iterating past the length of the array. This will throw an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException` when `i` reaches the value `length`

```
int length = splitarray.length;
double[] Exprs_Val=new double[length] ;
for (int i = 1; i< length+1; i++) //"i" will reach value == length, which is out of bounds
{ 
    System.out.println (splitarray[i]);
    Exprs_Val[i-1]=Double.parseDouble(splitarray[i]);
}
```

2:

"GSM119944" is not a valid number. What makes you think you will be able to parse it into a double? Do you mean to extract the portion after "GSM*" ?

Answer (score 0):

What does your input look like. When you're parsing the array elements into a double it is throwing an error because your String element contains alphabetical characters.

Comment: ive pasted it into the question at tht top